# Mongoid not save embedded documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to save Card into Board (Board is persisted):

```
def createCard(user, board, section, color)
    res = false
    ua = UserAccount.find_by(username: user)
    board = Board.find_by(_id: board)
    card = Card.new
    card.section = section
    card.color = color
    card.changes
    board.cards << card
    return card
end
```

This method return Card with persisted ID but if I search board, this doesn't contain any cards field.

Comment: You just new a Cart instance but not save it to database.

Comment: "board.cards << card" it saves card. Thank you

Comment: Oh, maybe you need to check if cart is saved successful, see `cart.errors`.

Comment: You were right, I had errors in Card. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had validation errors in Card, I have solve it adding to service method:

```
...
if card.valid?
  board.cards << card
  return card
else
  return card.errors
end
...
```

Thanks to "dddd1919"

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the board after adding a card record to it, in order to changes to take effect. before you return card:

```
 def createCard(user, board, section, color)
    #...
    board.save
    return card
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this don't work.
Mongoid doc:
    Model#{name}.<<
    Model#{name}.push
    Push a new document onto the relation. If the parent is
    persisted, then the child documents will be automatically
    saved.

So I don't have any idea about where is my error.

Comment: I agree, but in your example you are not persisting the parent document which is `board`, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Also try to create a new `card` through the parent document like this: `card = board.cards.build`

Comment: Yes, board is saved, I'm trying to add new card. I'll try using build. Thanks!